# Auth differentiation between XHR and standard execute

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I have the following method

```
private function adminRequired($accessControl)
{
    $user = new \CloseCall\ValueObject\User(2);
    if(!$accessControl->isAdmin($user)) {
        header("location: /auth");
        http_response_code(401);
    }
}
```

Within my controller, this method is always ran as the controller is constructed to check whether a user has admin priveleges or not.

The issue I'm having with this is that XHR requests can also be sent to this controller and a `header` redirect is not suitable for this, in this case I would want to send a 401 http response back to the javascript and handle this response there.

If I send a header redirect then an http response code then the header redirect is skipped when executing the controller normally.

If I send the response code and then the header redirect then the javascript tries to XHR to my /auth controller.

My question is how can I either differentiate between an XHR request and a standard execute or better yet, handle this gracefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there is no way to tell the difference.

Usually, you would add extra headers to the request. The most RESTful way to do that would be to use the `Accept` header.

e.g.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

… to say that you prefer JSON as the response format.

The server can then test to see if JSON is prefered over HTML and then assume it wants an API style response (rather an HTML response).

A less RESTful and more hacky approach is to use a completely custom header:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-requested-with", "xmlhttprequest");
```